# CSS / Jquery How to auto-size containers and images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with getting a particular jQuery library (Windy Slider) to auto-size. I have uploaded the code into CodePen which can be found here http://codepen.io/zyoung0206/pen/rLmXbV

The problem I am having is that, when you click the wireframe & mockups blue circle button, a window should popup with a image slider inside it. These container codes are:

```
.windy-demo {
    /*width: 1024px;*/
    width: 60%;
    margin: 40px auto;
    color: #aaa;
}

.windy-demo ul.wi-container {
/*  width: 1044px;
    height: 788px;*/
    width: 60%;
    height: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

which can be found on top of the CSS portion of the CodePen. 
What I am accomplish is to make these containers 60% width of the screen, and if the image inside is too big (let's say, the container is 800px width but image is 1024px), then the image to resize to fit inside the container.

I have tried manually setting the width of the containers (which resulted in fixed pixels of window size) and then tried setting it as width: 60%, but it is not working out well for the images that are larger than the container.

Comment: You can try setting max-width:100%; max-height:100% to the image.

Comment: @NitinGarg Awesome, that works, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think  `img { width: 100%; height: auto; }` will do it. I have just played around with your fiddle and as far as I can see, this should work.
I have just updated my answer, these are the first lines of CSS that worked for me, rebuilding your example locally:

```
   .windy-demo {
        width: 60%;
        margin: 40px auto;
        color: #aaa;
    }

    .windy-demo ul.wi-container {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;

        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }
    .windy-demo ul.wi-container li {
        display: block; /* Make list items to block in order to stretch 100% */
        overflow-y: hidden; /* Hides the scroll bar y-axis */
    }
    .windy-demo ul.wi-container li img {
        width: 100%; /* makes the image fit 100% of available space */
        height: auto;
    }
    .windy-demo h4 {
        padding: 0 10px;
        line-height: 26px;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .windy-demo ul.wi-container li {
        padding: 0;
        border: 10px solid #fff;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
    #slider ......
```

Comment: I have tried the height: auto but then the scrollbar on the bottom is within the image. Do I have to make the image / scrollbar as inline-block format to keep the scrollbar to relocate to bottom of the photo and to be centered?

Comment: My apology, I have tried your edited method however, I am running into two problems. 
First is that, the images are being displayed as compressed size, on the top left corner of the container (wish I could upload an image here).
Second is that, as you slide through the photo, it is the same photo (carrot) until you slide reversely, then forward again. 

The first problem: maybe it is missing a "width: 100%;"  inside the .windy-demo ul.wi-container{} ? or was the blank line in your comment intentional.

Comment: Second problem, when I erase these lines 

    `.windy-demo ul.wi-container li {
        display: block; /* Make list items to block in order to stretch 100% */
        overflow-y: hidden; /* Hides the scroll bar y-axis */
    }`

it starts scrolling through images without refreshing the same image. However, the scroll bar is then misplaced.

Comment: I was not able to find a working download of windy.js. As it seems, this library is pretty old, and I was not able to get your example working locally. Thus making it hard to get it to work. Provide a download of windy.js and I'll see what I can do. Where can I get that windy.js library?

Comment: It is here [http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/09/windy-a-plugin-for-swift-content-navigation/] (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/09/windy-a-plugin-for-swift-content-navigation/) , demo 3. Sorry about not attaching this earlier

Comment: I have fiddled it together. However, it still needs some tweeking and is not finished yet, but I have to go to sleep now. See my demo here http://sandbox.clickadelic.de/windy-responsive-modal/